# oracle xe prompts removal of kubuntu desktop 12.04

Tags: oracle

I was trying to install oracle-xe 10g on Kubuntu 12.04 x64. I had to install the i386 version of `bc` and it prompted me to remove kubuntu desktop and cups printing driver.

```
sudo apt-get install bc:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgpm2:i386 libncurses5:i386 libreadline6:i386 libtinfo5:i386
Suggested packages:
  gpm:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bc bluez-cups cups hplip kubuntu-desktop printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bc:i386 libgpm2:i386 libncurses5:i386 libreadline6:i386 libtinfo5:i386
```

After installing oracle-xe, if I try to install back kubuntu desktop, it prompts to remove oracle-xe.

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop cups
[sudo] password for sysadmin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libreadline6:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bc bluez-cups hplip printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp
Suggested packages:
  cups-pdf hplip-gui hplip-doc python-notify system-config-printer gutenprint-doc gutenprint-locales
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bc:i386 oracle-xe-universal:i386
```

Is there no way to keep both?

Comment: Also looking for it...

Answer (score 0):

I found an workaround:

Instead of trying to install `bc:i386`, which removes `bc` and other essential packages, I did the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.1_i386.deb
```

Pay attention to the **`--force-all`** argument. This makes `dpkg` ignore, besides the different arch, the pseudo-missing `bc:i386` dependency, which doesn't cause any harm since the normal (x86_64) `bc` dependency is enough.

Don't forget to follow all the other steps, as usual. A good guide is here: http://justalittlebrain.wordpress.com/2008/05/12/how-to-install-oracle-xe-in-ubuntu-64-bit/

So far, so good!

Comment: It really works, but apt-get started complaining about packages with unmet dependencies, so I ended up removing the `bc` dependency from the oracle deb, like this: http://superuser.com/questions/95509/tell-aptitude-to-ignore-broken-package